# scala : how to inititialize a val with a check

Tags: javascript, scala

In javascript there the logical OR is super useful in :

Given:

```
var sth = null;
var obj = sth || {};    // obj  will be an empty object 
var obj2 = sth || 'a';  // obj2 will be 'a'
```

is there anything similar for scala?

Comment: Define "empty obj". If you mean a null value, those should be avoided in the first place.

Comment: no not a null value. that s the thing

Comment: It' can be useful in JS because of the extensive ways an object can be treated as a boolean true/false. Empty string, undefined, zero, null, Nan etc. all come out as `false`. Scala doesn't do that (and rightly, in my view, it's an endless cause of issues in JS). As @dcastro's answer shows, if something can exist or not, use an `Option`. Then your code represents exactly what you mean, and you won't get blindsided by unexpected conversions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an object may or may not exist, then it should be wrapped in an `Option[A]` - in which case, you can use `getOrElse`

```
val userOpt: Option[User] = db.getUser(id)
val user: User = userOpt getOrElse defaultUser
```

If you're talking about an arbitrary condition, then use:

```
val obj = if(condition) x else y
```

Comment: Note that when using guards on assignment like that, you probably want to state the type of `obj` so you aren't surprised by type inference in case `x` and `y` aren't exactly the same type.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct answer to this is the second part of what dcastro said about using an if expression on the left side of the equal sign.

```
val obj = if(condition) x else y
```

I wanted to elaborate some on that. I expect that the author of the question and others who like the approach used in JavaScript, Python, and other dynamic languages might find this to be verbose and prefer the use of `||` instead. The problem with this is that it only works when you are working in a language with little to no static type safety. In a language with good type safety, `||` is an operator that works on booleans and results in a boolean. Giving it arguments that aren't booleans is a type error. The `||` shortcut in JavaScript and other scripting languages only works because the arguments to `||` do not have to be boolean and all values have a natural 'truthy' or 'falsy' nature.